# I can't reach my containers using docker java api client ( windows 10 ) timeout reached

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, containers, docker-api

I need to list all my containers which are up with docker compose file in windows .

this is my code :

```
public void listContainer() {
        DefaultDockerClientConfig config
          = DefaultDockerClientConfig.createDefaultConfigBuilder()
            .withDockerHost("tcp://192.168.65.2:9200").build();
        DockerClient dockerClient = DockerClientBuilder
                  .getInstance(config)
                  .build();
        List<Container> containers = dockerClient.listContainersCmd().exec() ;      
                for(Container container : containers) {
            System.out.println(container.getId()); 

        }
    }
```

**java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect**

this is my log file :

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:503) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:492) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:648) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply(ApacheConnector.java:483) ~[jersey-apache-connector-2.35.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:297) ~[jersey-client-2.35.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$invoke$2(JerseyInvocation.java:687) ~[jersey-client-2.35.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.call(JerseyInvocation.java:697) ~[jersey-client-2.35.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$runInScope$3(JerseyInvocation.java:691) ~[jersey-client-2.35.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292) ~[jersey-common-2.35.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274) ~[jersey-common-2.35.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:205) ~[jersey-common-2.35.jar:na]
```

those are my containers :

[image]

Comment: Did you change the port? 9200 is not the default docker port, iirc.

Comment: how can i know the default docker port ?